# In a (frameworkless) Javascript-based Single Page App, the URL queryString updates but the script fails to parse the updated URL

Tags: javascript, state, query-string

I'm learning about **state management** in the context of frameworkless javascript-based apps and thought I'd experiment with keeping a complete record of state in the URL `queryString`.

I've developed a setup where the URL `queryString` contains a small number of parameters, some corresponding to `boolean variables`, others to `string variables`.

Any user-interaction with the UI initiates a **two-step** process:

1. the user interaction updates the corresponding parameters in the `queryString`
2. immediately after the `queryString` updates, *another script* parses the `queryString` to translate the new representation of the app state into real changes across the app

Essentially, the `queryString` operates as the [single source of truth](http://www.hackingwithreact.com/read/1/12/state-and-the-single-source-of-truth) (**SSOT**) at the heart of the app.

Parsing the `queryString` in **Step 2** provides the settings to populate various custom data-* attributes with values and initiate various functions throughout the app. This is probably more easily demonstrated with an example, so...

**Simplified Example:**

```js
const section = document.getElementsByTagName('section')[0];
const div1 = document.getElementsByClassName('div1')[0];
const div2 = document.getElementsByClassName('div2')[0];

let queryString = '?';

const appState = {
  'div1-color': 'red',
  'div1-shape': 'circle',
  'div2-color': 'blue',
  'div2-shape': 'square'
};

const updateQueryString = (appState) => {
  
  const queryStringArray = [];

  for (let appStateKey in appState) {
    queryStringArray.push(appStateKey + '=' + appState[appStateKey]);
  }
  
  queryString = '?' + queryStringArray.join('&');
  
  console.log('QueryString: ' + queryString);
  
  // ^^^
  // THIS FINAL LINE IS FOR THE SAKE OF THIS EXAMPLE
  // IN THE REAL APP, THE FINAL LINE IS:
  // window.history.pushState({}, document.title, 'https://example.com/?' + queryString);
}

const updateApp = (queryString) => {

  let urlParams = new URLSearchParams(queryString);

  for (let entry of urlParams.entries()) {
        
    let key = 'data-' + entry[0];
    let value = entry[1];

    section.setAttribute(key, value);
  }
}

const updateAppState = (e) => {

  const target = e.target.className;
  switch (e.type) {
  
    case ('mouseover') :
      appState[target + '-color'] = (appState[target + '-color'] === 'red') ? 'blue' : 'red';
      break;
    
    case ('click') :
      appState[target + '-shape'] = (appState[target + '-shape'] === 'circle') ? 'square' : 'circle';
      break;
  }
  
  updateQueryString(appState);
  updateApp(queryString);
}

div1.addEventListener('mouseover', updateAppState, false);
div1.addEventListener('click', updateAppState, false);
div2.addEventListener('mouseover', updateAppState, false);
div2.addEventListener('click', updateAppState, false);
```

```css
h2 {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 16px;
}

[class^="div"] {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: 12px;
  width: 80px;
  height: 80px;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: all 0.6s linear;
}

[data-div1-color="red"] .div1 {
  background-color: rgb(255, 0, 0);
}

[data-div1-color="blue"] .div1 {
  background-color: rgb(0, 0, 191);
}

[data-div2-color="red"] .div2 {
  background-color: rgb(255, 0, 0);
}

[data-div2-color="blue"] .div2 {
  background-color: rgb(0, 0, 191);
}

[data-div1-shape="circle"] .div1 {
  border-radius: 50%;
}

[data-div1-shape="square"] .div1 {
  border-radius: 0;
}

[data-div2-shape="circle"] .div2 {
  border-radius: 50%;
}

[data-div2-shape="square"] .div2 {
  border-radius: 0;
}
```

```html
<h2>Mouseover to change colour, click to change shape:</h2>

<section
  data-div1-color="red"
  data-div1-shape="circle"
  data-div2-color="blue"
  data-div2-shape="square"
>

  <div class="div1"></div>
  <div class="div2"></div>

</section>
```

The example above works as intended, because, in order to demonstrate the setup on Stack Overflow, I don't want to start messing about with updating URLs while the browser is pointing at `stackoverflow.com`.

The issue I have *in the real app* is that even though the `queryString` updates, it is **never** being parsed correctly.

The data parsed from the `queryString` suggests the `queryString` isn't updating at all.

Yet, when I check the `queryString`, it has definitely updated.

If the `queryString` is updating, why isn't it being parsed correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I spent some more time thinking about this.

I concluded that, most likely, what was happening in this code:

```
updateQueryString(appState);
updateApp(window.location.search);
```

is that in the first function

```
updateQueryString(appState)
```

the final line

```
window.history.pushState({}, document.title, 'https://example.com/?' + queryString);
```

*hasn't completed updating* the current URL, before the second function

```
updateApp(window.location.search)
```

reaches up and grabs `window.location.search`.

So, in summary, where I thought I was dealing with a **synchronous process**, I'm actually looking at an **asychronous process**.

---

### Solution Attempt #1 - Change the Single Source of Truth (SSOT)

It occurred to me that while the URL didn't update almost instantaneously, the `appState object` *did*.

Which raised the possibility that I might use the `appState object` as the **SSOT** instead of the `queryString`.

And then the `appState` would inform *both* the `queryString` *and* provide the new representation of the app state which could be translated into real changes across the app.

I rejected this possible solution for two reasons:

1. I didn't want it to be the case that, in the event of a miscommunication, the state of the app didn't *exactly align* with the representation of the app state in the `queryString`. This would be impossible where the `queryString` played the role of **SSOT**, but it would become a distinct possibility where the `queryString` was only a translation (or *mis-translation*) of the `appState object`.
2. In the example above, the `appState object` plays the role of *a helper*, ensuring that the state resulting from any user interaction is correctly represented in the `queryString`. Because the example is a simple one, the `appState object` represents the state of the app in its entirety (effectively duplicating the representation in the `queryString`). But I definitely want it to be the case that the helper may communicate to the `queryString` *only* the updated parts of the state. If the `appState object` were to adopt the role of **SSOT** then it would always need to represent the entire state of the app.

---

### Solution Attempt #2 - Use the `popstate` event

Since I only want to invoke

```
updateApp(window.location.search)
```

*after* the `queryString` has updated, I can straightforwardly use `window.onpopstate`. The easiest way to do this would be to add an `Event Listener` as the very last line of `updateQueryString(appState)`, like so:

```
window.history.pushState({}, document.title, 'https://example.com/?' + queryString);
window.addEventListener('popstate', updateApp);
```

That way, `updateApp()` only starts executing, after `window.history.pushState` has completed.

---

### Final Solution

**Solution #2** is perfectly good, but it struck me that I could invoke `updateApp` even sooner by regarding `window.history.pushState` as a **side-effect** (rather than the main outcome) of `updateQueryString(appState)` and rethink the function so that the last two lines of the function would include this `return` statement, instead:

```
window.history.pushState({}, document.title, 'https://example.com/?' + queryString);
return queryString;
```

This means that `updateApp()` *doesn't even have to wait* for `window.history.pushState` to complete.

Instead, `updateApp()` can work straight away on the data returned by `updateQueryString(appState)`, even while that function is still updating the `queryString`.

**Solution:**

Change the first line of `updateApp()` from:

```
let urlParams = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search);
```

to:

```
let urlParams = new URLSearchParams(updateQueryString(appState));
```

Replace every instance of:

```
updateQueryString(appState);
updateApp();
```

with:

```
updateApp(appState);
```